# Mysterious 8 second delay in boot after grub

Tags: fedora, kernel, boot, grub, delay

I have installed Fedora 23 (KDE spin) on an HP Prodesk mini 600 G2. There is one problem I can't quite figure out, though: after grub comes up, and I press <kbd>enter</kbd> on any kernel to boot, the screen goes black with a blinking underscore cursor and then there is a mysterious 8 second delay. There is no hard drive/SSD activity during that period. Then after, BAM, there is a flurry of activity over the next 4 seconds and it is finished booting.

Try as I may, I can't figure out what that delay is. But I know it shouldn't be there. Even if it were just waiting on something, if I had *some* message telling me what it is doing, that would be helpful. I am doing nothing special. No RAID, no encryption, just two partitions (root and swap).

Things that made no difference:

- I uninstalled Plymouth.
- I tried booting with UEFI and with BIOS.
- I tried a Fedora live boot DVD instead of booting from the SSD install.
- I tried same thing with USB key boot.
- I disabled a bunch of stuff like abrtd and ModemManager.
- Removed the "quiet" flag in the kernel invocation.
- Rebuilt with dracut.
- I even tried booting 23 on our Lenovo laptops (a totally different machine with different chipset and other hardware) and on some Intel NUCs and had the same delay. On our Intel NUC, using Fedora 21, there is the same delay but only 4 seconds (???!!!) But if I try a different distro, such as Archbang, there is no such delay at all.

I thought maybe "systemd-analyze" would help, but it doesn't show that delay: it says "4.3 seconds" which is the time AFTER the 8 second delay - further indicating the delay is after/during grub but before loading the kernel. My Internet searching has produced nothing. Even if I can't get rid of the delay, having some message on the screen would be useful because it looks like the machine is dead during that period.

Comment: what does dmesg say

Comment: In addition to removing 'quiet', try also removing 'rhgb'.

Comment: Dmesg shows nothing of interest.  "rhgb" didn't add any additional info either.  Meanwhile, we tied Fedora 21 and it does the same thing!  Tried lots of grub changes, nothing.  Replaced GRUB with isolinux, same 8 second pause.  Tried bootchart with  initcall_debug printk.time=y init=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart  no additional help.  This is really annoying!

Comment: Oh, I tried the debug kernel- no additional info there either.